# Widget on task bar for currency conversion

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, widgets

Is there a way to have a widget for currency conversions (enter a value of currency A so the price for that value on currency B) on the taskbar? (like the default windows 10 for the weather for example) ?

Or at least have it floating on top no matter which window/program is the main one or in full screen.

Windows calculator is not very useful cause it has only 2 decimals and I need to manually launch it and then when I dont need it I need to manually set it back to be a normal calculator...